# my dialog node missed during the creation of mfc project

Tags: .net, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc

[image]I have resource file like (.rc and .rc2). how can i add my dailog nodes from exisiting rescources. is it possible to recover my dialog nodes into my current projects.
Actually dialog node parts are not visible in Resource view window.

please help me .thanks in advance..

Comment: What is a _dialog node_?

Comment: @ Michael Walz  .sir that is exactly a design page.(UI) .I cant view designer.but codes exist in the project. I want to view that designer, then only I can work on that project. Actually that designer form is missing from the project.Any solution please help me.I still struggling on that area.I have not much knowledge in MFC  .

Comment: That is exactly a dialog box

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a59ha6t.aspx

Comment: You can display the Resource tab by clicking on **Resource View** from the **View** menu.

Comment: @ Andrew Truckle. i just follow the same,and also i  am  able to view the menu.but i want menu with designer.(Dialog missing).

Comment: please see the above screen shot. i cant see the dialog area marked with red color.when open resource view.Actually that area missing from project.how i can restore my UI design.

Comment: @ Andrew Truckle.My dialog box actually hidden in that project.how to show that.any solution.

Comment: You seem to have the calculator visible. Just some of the controls off the display? Try resizing the calcular window to make it winder temporarily to see the rest of the content. Otherwise, open up the RC file in a text editor, locate the calculator resource and show us the actual code from the RC file for the dialog. It will show us the mechanics of the dialog.

Comment: @ Barmak Shemirani .sir your shortcut is correct.but unable to view that dialog box.

Comment: @Andrew Truckle.sir I will give you the actual code from the RC file for the dialog.please give me your skypeid,emailid for contact. my skype id : prince tomy.please ping me.

Comment: ajtruckle is my skype ID. Note that in tagging a commenter don’t put a space after the @ and their tag ID will not have spaces. If you are on a PC type @ and pick the name.

Comment: thanks @Andrew Truckle.

Comment: @Andrew Truckle.You are really helpful .You have given me complete solution .you are a great man.

Comment: @Prince Happy to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for sending me your project. If you right-click your existing resource content and select **Resource Includes**:

[image: Resource Includes]

This then displays a popup window:

[image: Resource Includes Dialog Box]

Notice the section I have highlighted in Yellow? You are including all your references from *external* files. When you check on the MSDN Library about the [Resource Includes Dialog Box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/resource-includes-dialog-box?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(vc.editors.resourceincludes)%26rd%3Dtrue) you will see the following statement:

> **Compile-time directives**
>
> Allows you to include resource files that are
>   **created and edited separately from the resources in your main resource**
>   **file**, contain compile-time directives (such as those that
>   conditionally include resources), or contain resources in a custom
>   format. You can also use the Compile-time directives box to include
>   standard MFC resource files. For more information, see [Including Resources at Compile Time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/how-to-include-resources-at-compile-time).

In the related link above it also states reasons why you would have the resources in a external file:

[image: Notes]

It seems to me that if you are wanting to edit these resources visually there must be another project where they were managed. Thus, at the moment, you must edit them yourself.

The only other thing you can potentially do is combine the contents of the external RC files into your main RC file and remove the `#include` statements but I do not know if that is practicle in your case.